# MS ACCESS 2007 ERROR: #NAME?

Tags: language, microsoft-access-2007, microsoft-office-2007

That error is shown in a Date field (month name) and year in a report.
It could be because Windows is in spanish and Office in english?

Comment: Details, please.

Comment: Is the query that feeds the report showing the data correctly?

Comment: Is the name of the field "Date"? The #Name error usually indicates that there is an ambiguity with a name that can't be resolved because there's more than one thing in the relevant namespace with that name.